# Multiple text field in one fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, form-for, fields-for

I'm building Project Management application and I'm creating Project with `form_for` but inside it I want a `fields for` to create 3 students.

I've set up my `new.html.erb` for Projects like this:

```
<h1>Creating new project</h1>

<%= form_for :project, url: projects_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :lecturer %>
    <%= f.text_field :lecturer %>
  </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.fields_for :students do |s| %>
            <%= s.label :name %>
            <%= s.text_field :name %><br>
            <%= s.label :name %>
            <%= s.text_field :name %><br>
            <%= s.label :name %>
            <%= s.text_field :name %>
        <% end %>
    </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

And for the `create` method jusst added one simple line to see my `form_for` result:

```
  def create
    render text: params[:project].inspect
  end
```

So when I fill up the text fields on page and hit submit all I get is `{"name"=>"asd", "lecturer"=>"ffff", "students"=>{"name"=>"qeew"}}` so as you can see only my last student was passed to this dictionary.

How can I create multiple students in one `fields_for`? Or how can I set up these two models to work with each other. I hope you get my point of view and know what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build the number of students you need to have fields for in your controller `new` action like follows:

```
# app/controllers/projects_controller.rb

def new
  @project = Project.new
  3.times do 
    student = @project.students.build
  end
end
```

This will build three students under project instance.

Then update your view's `form_for` declaration as follows:

```
# app/views/projects/new.html.erb

<%= form_for @project, url: projects_path do |f| %> 
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :lecturer %>
    <%= f.text_field :lecturer %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.fields_for :students do |s| %>
      <%= s.label :name %>
      <%= s.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: No issues. I edited it via my  cell phone, so the syntax highlighting was not set properly. I see you edited it again :-)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to pass in a proper `Project` object, instead of initializing it off of a symbol. Then, add three students to the object, and do a fields for the entire collection.

To do this, you'd want some code like this in `projects#new` -

```
@project = Project.new
3.times { @project << Student.new }
```

Then over in the form:

```
form_for @project do |f|
  ...
  f.fields_for :students do |s|
    s.label :name
    s.text_field :name
  end
end
```

The `fields_for` will automatically generate separate fields for each student that you added to the project in the controller.

---

One point I'm not entirely sure about: I *think* this will require you add a line `accepts_nested_attibutes_for :students` in your `Project` model, but I'm not quite sure. This does have the added advantage that you can create the students and the project quite easily in the create action in the controller, but isn't the right choice in every situation. If my solution does appear to require `accepted_nested_attributes_for` and you don't want it, let me know and I can update my answer with a similar, if more painful, solution.